# In Qt Creator, examples are missed

Tags: qt, qt-creator, archlinux

Installed Qt Creator 2.8 in ArchLinux
Installed qt5-* (* as every related package) using pacman

examples were not available in the repositories so I used the one in the AUR, qt5-examples

examples are installed under /usr/share/doc/qt/examples

qmake-qt5 -query says:

```
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/usr
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/usr/lib/qt
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/usr/share/qt
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/usr/share/doc/qt
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/usr/include/qt
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/usr/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/usr/lib/qt/libexec                                                                                                              
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/usr/lib/qt/bin                                                                                                                      
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/usr/tests                                                                                                                          
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/usr/lib/qt/plugins                                                                                                               
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:/usr/lib/qt/imports                                                                                                               
QT_INSTALL_QML:/usr/lib/qt/qml                                                                                                                       
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/usr/share/qt/translations                                                                                                   
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:/etc/xdg                                                                                                                    
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/usr/share/doc/qt/examples                                                                                                       
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/usr/share/doc/qt/examples                                                                                                          
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/usr                                                                                                                                  
QT_HOST_DATA:/usr/lib/qt                                                                                                                             
QT_HOST_BINS:/usr/lib/qt/bin                                                                                                                         
QT_HOST_LIBS:/usr/lib                                                                                                                                
QMAKE_SPEC:linux-g++                                                                                                                                 
QMAKE_XSPEC:linux-g++                                                                                                                                
QMAKE_VERSION:3.0
QT_VERSION:5.1.0
```

which means examples are in the right place

But they are not shown in Qt Creator!

[image: Qt Creator Examples]

How can I bring them in qtcreator?

PS: I don't wanna forget about the solution and install SDK.

Comment: Look this link
http://askubuntu.com/questions/450983/ubuntu-14-04-qtcreator-qt5-examples-missing This works for me.

Answer (score 11):

I know OP asked for archlinux but I faced the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04. To solve it I had to install the following two packages:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples qtbase5-doc-html
```

This will show the basic `widget` examples.

[Additional examples](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qt%20examples) (e.g. qt quick) can be added by installing them explicitly:

```
sudo apt install qtquickcontrols2-5-examples
```

To actually get them displayed in `qtcreator` I had to install:

```
sudo apt install qt5-doc qt5-doc-html
```

Here is the output of `echo $(apt-mark showmanual | grep -P '(libqt|qt)')`

```
cmake-qt-gui qt5-default qt5-doc qt5-doc-html qtbase5-dev qtbase5-doc-html qtbase5-examples qtcreator qtquickcontrols2-5-examples
```

Edit:

Also make sure to install the qml modules you need, for example:

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls2
```

Comment: Hi, I just ran into the same issue (on Ubuntu 20.04) and hoped your answer would help, but unfortunately it didn't. Still +1 for the time you took to answer. Here's my output of `echo $(apt-mark showmanual|grep -P '^(libqt|qt)')`: `qt5-default qt5-doc qt5-doc-html qtbase5-examples qtcharts5-examples qtcreator qtcreator-doc`. What am I missing? Could you check which other Qt5-related packages you have installed?

Comment: Hah, the examples are there (on Ubuntu 20.04). They're located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples` for me, which is owned by `root:root` and not writable to normal users. A simple check with `sudo` proves they show up as soon as QtCreator finds them writable.

Comment: I also noticed that one _could_ potentially (but probably shouldn't) manipulate [qt.conf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) to bend the location to one's will. Or simply copy and subsequently `chown` the examples in some user-writable location. Which is what I am going to do. Please respond to me if a better solution becomes available.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer with the output of the command you provided. For me the examples are also located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/` and owned by `root:root`. When I want to open them, qt creator asks if the example project should be copied to a writable location.

Comment: I found the actual reason this didn't work for me. Apparently `qmake` is central to this whole business. In particular `qmake -query` shows details about the Qt versions it knows about. Now when I freshly installed QtCreator and all that, I still couldn't see the examples. However, inside the Options there is one tab to configure "Qt Versions". In my case nothing was configured after freshly installing the packages. I needed to point it to `/usr/bin/qmake` which in turn "auto-detected" the Qt I wanted to use. After that, the examples became visible.

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator Examples are added in Official Repository 'Extra'

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/qt5-examples/

install it using :-

```
sudo pacman -S qt5-examples
```

Comment: I had been incorrectly searching for qtcreator examples. Found what I needed thanks to this.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the installation location of the examples and open the `.pro` project file with qt-creator.

Alternatively if you just want to build and run the example. Navigate to the directory `qmake` and then `make` and then simple run the output

Additionally if you strictly require the examples to show in the IDE, try launching with admin privileges as the installation directory of the examples may require admin privileges.

Comment: thanks, but why they are not shown in the examples section in qt creator?

Comment: It was empty too, @mdoran3844

Comment: i'm all out of ideas. You have any luck?

Comment: Fascinating, you're perfectly right. I tried the packaged version of the examples on Ubuntu (20.04) and they didn't show up. Starting with `sudo` made them appear ... very very strange. But a closer look revealed why `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples` is owned by `root:root` and not writable to a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

My situation is that qt example folder has no permission to read and execute for non-root users, fixed it and everything OK. In your case:

```
sudo chmod +rx /usr/share/doc/qt/examples
```

Comment: Interesting, +1. Checked this and it doesn't apply for Ubuntu (20.04). In Ubuntu I have folders like `qtbase5-examples` under `/usr/share/doc`. And yes, I realize the question was for [tag:archlinux], but perhaps future readers using Ubuntu will find my comment useful. In Ubuntu examples are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples` and are owned by `root:root` and thus not writable to normal users. Perhaps an issue no one noticed?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using archlinux and have had the same problem. Despite not having the examples & demo installed the *qmake-qt5 -query* is printing a non-existence path.

It seems Qt5 examples are now on AUR(Arch User Repository).

To get the them

1. Download https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qt/qt5-examples/qt5-examples.tar.gz
2. Extract the package maybe with **$ tar xzf qt5-examples.tar.gz**
3. **cd qt5-examples** which contains the  PKGBUILD . Then run **makepkg** .This will download 165MB   *qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0.tar.xz*
4. Run **pacman -U qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0.tar.xz**

Answer (score 1):

Qtcreator cannot detect the example without its html file.

So, in my case I've already installed qtbase5-examples, but could not able to see examples in qtcreator.

After,

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-doc-html
```

examples are visible in qtcreator. It was the same with qt5serialport-examples.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5serialport-examples qtserialport5-doc-html
```

Have a nice one.

Answer (score -2):

make sure you run the qt-opensource-linux-x86-android-5.4.0.run like this:

```
$sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-android-5.4.0.run
```

please do not forget the "sudo"
or you will find that the examples in the qtcreator is missing.

Comment: Bad idea to run soemthing as sudo if you do not have to, try if you have Alston's problem, incorrect permissions on the example folder.