# Make Qt Creator to see examples and docs

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

I build *Qt 5.9.1* from sources, downloaded from [www.qt.io](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-5), on *Ubuntu 16.04.3*. I use `-make examples` for `configure` script when I build *Qt*.

After installation in default prefix `/usr/local` there is a `/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/examples/` and `/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/doc/`.

Also I have installed *Qt Creator 4.3.1* from the official site.

On the "Welcome" page of *Qt Creator* in "Examples" I see auto-detected "Qt 5.9.1 in PATH (Qt-5.9.1)" entry in combobox (on another installation I even don't see this entry - combobox is empty). And no one icon of the examples itself. Typing any sensible keywords into search box does nothing.

When I open my (perfetcly buildable) project and hit <kbd>F1</kbd> on any *Qt* class name, I expect to see a help on it in the right split window. Then nothing happens, but only "No documentation avaliable." text is shown.

`qmake` of installed *Qt* is in the `PATH` and there is `QTDIR=/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1` in `/etc/environment`.

How to make *Qt Creator* to see docs, examples and demos from auto-detected *Qt* installation?

Comment: I generally find it easiest to just install everything including at least one Qt version with the Qt Online installer (under Linux to user home directory). Then you can add your custom compiled Qt version, or your Linux distro's native Qt version to its Qt Creator installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Qt Creator, examples are missed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178796/in-qt-creator-examples-are-missed)

Answer (score 3):

In case someone installed `qtcreator` from the Ubuntu packages the examples can be installed in the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples qtbase5-doc-html
```

This will show the basic `widget` examples.

[Additional examples](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qt%20examples) (e.g. qt quick) can be added by installing them explicitly:

```
sudo apt install qtquickcontrols2-5-examples
```

To actually get them displayed in `qtcreator` I had to install:

```
sudo apt install qt5-doc qt5-doc-html
```

Edit:

Also make sure to install the qml modules you need, for example:

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls2
```

Answer (score 2):

Select `Tools → Options → Help → Documentation` in Qt Creator and add *.qch files from `/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/doc/` (and possibly from `/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/examples/` ?).

Comment: The problem was in qtmacextras submodule. `configure -skip qtmacextras` solves the problem. Then I need not just `make`, but also `make docs` and `make install_docs` too.